# Filter data based on personal ID

Tags: c#, database, linq

I would like display data based on their own personal data.

- The above is correct.
- I want the "else" statement display his/her own data.
- I added a "WHERE" on the else.

Hope u could help.
Thanks.

```
else
{
    using (DB.SASupportITEntities db = new DB.SASupportITEntities())
    {
        IQueryable<DB.ITCase1> dbIT = db.ITCase1;

        // Put any filter here before the next comment.
        // Example filter dbIT = dbIT.where(m => m.Department == ddlFilterDepartment.selectedValue);


        // Now start extract data from database.
        var result = (from tbCase in dbIT
                      join tbRequestor in db.View_SA_Employee on tbCase.Requestor equals tbRequestor.User_ID
                      join tbCloseBy in db.View_SA_Employee on tbCase.CloseBy equals tbCloseBy.User_ID into outerCloseBy
                      from tbCloseBy in outerCloseBy.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      join tbDept in db.View_SA_Department on tbCase.Department equals tbDept.Department_Code
                      //// where  aa => aa.User_ID == aa.selectedValue 
                      select new
                      {
                          tbCase.Area,
                          tbCase.Case_ID,
                          tbCase.CloseBy,
                          tbCase.CloseDate,
                          tbCase.CloseRemark,
                          tbCase.CreationDate,
                          tbCase.Department,
                          tbCase.DepartmentCharge,
                          tbCase.DocNo,
                          tbCase.NormalService,
                          tbCase.OtherService,
                          tbCase.Purpose,
                          RequestorName = tbRequestor.User_Name,
                          CloseByName = tbCloseBy.User_Name,
                          tbDept.Department_Name
                      }
                     ).ToList();

        gridHistory.DataSource = result;
        gridHistory.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify your question? I am not sure what exactly you are asking. My guess is you want to dynamically add a where clause to your query. Is that correct?